# How can I play a mp3 file via adb command with google play music on android kitkat 9?

Tags: android, command, adb

adb shell input keyevent 126 is working for Android 4.4.4 to click on Play/Pause button But the same command is not working for Android version 9. What could be the adb command used to play on Android version 9?

Answer (score 0):

[image: If you wanna use] 
As you can see media play/pause key events were added on api 11. You can try

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

if you making an app for one device only